# Problema javascript ao receber variável com data

Tags: php, javascript

```
<td class="A8" style="text-align:center;">
    <?php
    $dta_inicial = $dados['data_inicial'];
    var_dump($dta_inicial);
    ?>
    <div class="B2" onclick="preencheform_edicaoJS(<?php echo $dados['etapa_projeto_id']; ?>,<?php echo $dados['etapa_id']; ?>,<?php echo $dados['dias_total']; ?>,<?php echo $dta_inicial; ?>)">
        <img src='resources/images/andremachado/editar.png' width='20' title='Editar' alt='editar' border = '0' />
    </div>
</td>
```

No `var_dump` aparece corretamente a variável `$dta_inicial`, mas no javascript ao dar `alert` aparece um valor errado.

```
function preencheform_edicaoJS(etapa_projeto_id,etapa_id,dias_total,data_inicial){
    alert(data_inicial);
}
```

Mas se eu setar o $dta_inicial = 3;, ele envia certinho o 3, só não vai quando fica a data mesmo, formatada, aparece uns numeros 0.2324934334 ...

Comment: Qual o formato da data? Se for XX/XX/XX, acho que o JS está fazendo divisão com a data, por isso o 0.232xxxx... Tenta colocar `<?php echo "$dta_inicial"; ?>`... com `"`...

Comment: @gustavox Acho que você identificou corretamente o problema. Mas as aspas é pra estar dentro do `echo` ou fora? E a propósito, no caso precisam ser aspas simples, do contrário vai dar conflito com o código chamador.

Comment: Você tem razão @mgibsonbr, as aspas ficaram no local errado, e devem ser simples mesmo... foi desatenção, mas esta não é mesmo uma pergunta que eu me achasse capaz  de responder, porque por mais que tenha identificado o problema, não saberia como explicar a solução (ainda que as aspas estivessem certas hehe) com a perfeição que vc fez. +1 Pense no meu comentário acima como uma rolada de bola do entusiasta para o especialista (que ele sabia que vinha logo atrás). :-) +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se sua variável `$dta_inicial` contém uma string representando uma data (ex.: `17/12/2015`) e você faz um `echo` dessa variável, então seu conteúdo será inserido como tal na saída. Ou seja, isso:

```php
preencheform_edicaoJS(...,<?php echo $dta_inicial; ?>)
```

Vai acabar gerando isso:

```js
preencheform_edicaoJS(...,17/12/2015)
```

E como JavaScript não possui um literal para datas, isso será interpretado como uma expressão numérica (como [apontado por gustavox nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104491/problema-javascript-ao-receber-vari%C3%A1vel-com-data#comment214133_104491)) e então avaliada (resultando em um número).

Se você quer que o código JavaScript receba uma data, uma opção seria emitir o código que cria uma data:

```php
preencheform_edicaoJS(..., new Date('<?php echo $dta_inicial; ?>'))
```

Que funciona, mas só se a data estiver no formato mês/dia/ano:

```js
preencheform_edicaoJS(..., new Date('17/12/2015')) // Invalid Date
```

De modo que eu sugiro simplesmente passar a data como string mesmo e tratar do formato na própria função JavaScript (a menos que você ache mais fácil fazer isso no PHP, seu critério):

```php
preencheform_edicaoJS(...,'<?php echo $dta_inicial; ?>')
```

(repare no uso de aspas simples, é pra não entrar em conflito com o código chamador, que usa aspas duplas - `onclick="preencheform_edicaoJS(...)"`)

---

**Atualização:** se o que você quer no JavaScript é uma string mesmo (i.e. a *representação* de uma data, não um objeto `Date`), mas num formato diferente do que a sua variável `$dta_inicial` possui, é necessário converter de string pra data e então formatar a data de novo pra string.

Isso pode ser feito de maneira "formal" (usando métodos que lidam com datas, em uma ou outra linguagem, como [apontado em comentário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104491/problema-javascript-ao-receber-vari%C3%A1vel-com-data/104507?noredirect=1#comment214201_104507)), mas sendo um formato simples você pode também fazer manualmente, tipo assim:

```php
$dta_array = explode("/", $dta_inicial);
$dta_transformada = $dta_array[2] . "-" . $dta_array[1] . "-" . $dta_array[0];
...
preencheform_edicaoJS(...,'<?php echo $dta_transformada; ?>')
```

(inverta os índices `1` e `0` se a data originalmente estiver no formato mês/dia/ano)

Ou no lado JavaScript:

```js
var arr = data.split('/');
var str = arr[2] + "-" + arr[1] + "-" + arr[0];
```

Comment: Eu fiz algo assim e agora retorna a data corretamente, gracias a seu codigo, mas veio num formato estranho de data com mais coisas. Nao teria como eu enviar a data no formato americano já usando o new date, aquele ano-mes-dia, que parametro adiciono, que com ele já me resolve ?

Comment: @AndréSilveiraMachado Sim, experimente fazer `date_format($dta_inicial, 'm/d/Y')` antes de enviar pelo `echo`. Também funciona(ria) com `'Y-m-d'`, a diferença é que por alguma razão que desconheço o JavaScript tratará a primeira como hora local e a segunda como UTC (que na minha opinião não faz muito sentido, pois é só data e não data+hora...).

Comment: Só que eu só aconselho fazer um `new Date(...)` se você *realmente precisa* de um objeto `Date` - caso contrário, se for só pra exibir por exemplo, passe só a string mesmo, ainda que formatada pelo método acima.

Comment: Com o Date(...) funcionou, mas eu quero que ele ou envie no formato americano Y-m-d ou então o javascript na hora que receber ele, transforme neste formato, acho que a tua segunda dica não resolve, pois volta ao problema eu imagino.

Comment: Então... se o que você tem é uma string, e o que você quer é uma string (mas em outro formato), então você vai ter uma hora que converter essa string pra uma data e então formatar essa data de novo em string. Isso pode ser feito no PHP (via `DateTime::createFromFormat` e `format`) ou no JavaScript (via `new Date` e [`.toIsoString().slice(0,10)`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11172083/520779)).

Comment: Vou tentar formar o codigo ali na hora que ele recebe o javascript

Comment: Os codiso que voce inseriu na "Atualização" não funcionaram, mas vou tentar este new date do lado do javascript, estou levando a data no formato dia/mes/ano e dando um new Date no php e enviando, aí ele chega no javascript com Thu Jan 01 ..., é esse Thu jan 01... que estou tentando quebrar lá para dia/mes/ano.

Comment: Tambem nao funcionou este ultimo DateTime, voltei exatamente ao ponto inicial: 0.034398432478 ....

Código:

$fecha = new StdClass;
$fecha->innertext = $dta_inicial;

$eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $fecha->innertext);
if ( false===$eventDate ) {
  die('invalid date format');
}
$dado = $eventDate->format('Y-m-d');
$dado = $eventDate->format('d/m/Y');

________________________
Depois eu envio pro javascript o $dado e dou um alert, aparece errado.

Comment: Aqui está o codigo:
http://pastebin.com/ZNth06Xv

Comment: Eu estou realmente confuso, PHP não é meu forte... Acho que vou deixar pra alguém com mais experiência responder. :(